# Configuring node from hub machine Automatically using selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-grid

I want to set up the node in different machines using a bit of java code it is not possible always to start a node every time so I want to open nodes automatically from hub machine.i tried some of the executable jars like Selenium-Grid-Extras but it's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start a node automatically from hub, you can write a bit of code to to start the hub as well as starting nodes based on the machine details where the node should execute. You can use ssh to start a node on a linux instance. There are libraries available for doing so in Java. About Windows I am not sure, but there should be libraries to remotely start applications through java. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in windows is to create scheduled tasks on each node machine-- e.g.

`schtasks /create /tn RestartNode /tr c:\SeleniumGridExtras\RestartNode.bat /sc ONSTART`

(the sc doesn't seem to work but whatever)

then from jenkins you can call the scheduled task with

`schtasks /end /tn RestartNode /s [HOSTNAME] /u [DOMAIN]\[USERNAME] /p [PASSWORD]`